# Descargar PDF en el mismo navegador HTML2PDF

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pdf

Estoy generando un archivo en PDF con HTML2PDF y uso el siguiente codigo para que me mande a una ventana con el PDF ya generado:

```
require '../../pdf_new/vendor/autoload.php';
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
// get the HTML
ob_start();
require_once 'res/ver_factura_html.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P','A4','es','true','UTF-8');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
$html2pdf->Output('asd.pdf');
```

Hasta alli todo va de maravilla, pero eh estado buscando como descargar directamente el archivo pdf sin abrirme la otra pantalla y ley que necesito reemplazar la ultima linea por

```
$html2pdf->Output('asd.pdf', 'D');
```

Lo hice, pero me descarga en una nueva ventana mas no en la que yo estoy. Osea si yo estoy en **midominio.com/dashboard.php** quiero que me la descargue alli mas no en **midominio.com/res/ver_factura_html.php** que es en donde esta la plantilla que tomara HTML2PDF para poder generar el PDF.

Comment: No quedó muy claro cuál es tu duda. ¿Quieres mostrar HTML y descargar el PDF al mismo tiempo? ¿O qué es exactamente lo que necesitas?

Comment: Triby gracias por responder, edite la pregunta.